# SQL Server Format Date DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql-server, date, format

How can I get a date like 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS'
I tried the following but it's not exactly what I'm looking for...

```
select convert(varchar(20),getdate(),113)
```

result: **14 Jul 2011 09:23:57**

Thanks a lot
Largo

Comment: Also note if you want to show formatted dates in front end application, you should do formation there

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

You can concatenate it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```

Comment: @Imran's answer seems more comfortable if you are using SQL server 2012 or greater, `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')`. All credits to him

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada Agreed, but my answer was given in 2011 where SQL Server 2012 did not yet exist and my version works for older SQL Server versions too.

Comment: You are a Gem man! it would be a bit nice if you edit and include Imran's answer too as an update to your original answer. As most of the users would be using Sql server version 2012 or newer.

Answer (score 23):

A quick way to do it in sql server 2012 is as follows:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: The best answer to format the date, especially compared to those answers which mention the `Convert` function.

Comment: 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: A much better and clean solution, C# developers would also love this like me!

Comment: @shmnff it is available on SQL Server 2012 and later.

Answer (score 2):

You can learn datetime formatting in sql server here

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

http://yrbyogi.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/date-and-time-types-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),120)
```

Comment: This will give `2017-01-03 12:56:50` (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)