# SQL Time Format in DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, date, datetime, timezone, format

How can I use SQL to convert time from the raw format into DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss? 
My current code is the month before the date.

```
DECLARE @nDays int = 1
DECLARE @timeVal int = dbo.GetUnixTime(DATEADD(DAY, -@nDays,GETUTCDATE()))
DECLARE @csTimeZone    VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @duration int

SELECT @csTimeZone = timeZone FROM APP_CommCell WHERE id = 2

SELECT @csTimeZone = TimeZoneStdName FROM SchedTimeZone
WHERE  TimeZoneName = SUBSTRING(@csTimeZone, CHARINDEX(':', @csTimeZone, CHARINDEX(':', @csTimeZone, 0) + 1) + 1, 255)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT 
    jobid AS 'Job ID', 
    B.servStartDate AS 'Raw Format',
    dbo.UTCToLocalStringTime(dbo.GetDateTime(B.servStartDate),@csTimeZone) AS 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss'
FROM JMBkpStats B
```

Here is the result of the code above.

```
Job ID  Raw Format  MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss
2599    1410426012  09/11/2014 16:00:12
2611    1410432451  09/11/2014 17:47:31
2639    1410483605  09/12/2014 08:00:05
2724    1410541211  09/13/2014 00:00:11
2738    1410570009  09/13/2014 08:00:09
2750    1410598807  09/13/2014 16:00:07
2797    1410627614  09/14/2014 00:00:14
2808    1410656412  09/14/2014 08:00:12
2820    1410685211  09/14/2014 16:00:11
2847    1410714017  09/15/2014 00:00:17
2866    1410742805  09/15/2014 08:00:05
```

Result for *SELECT @csTimeZone = timeZone FROM APP_CommCell WHERE id = 2*

```
timeZone
0:-420:(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta
```

Partial result for *SELECT @csTimeZone = TimeZoneStdName FROM SchedTimeZone*

```
timezonename    TimeZoneStdName
(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta SE Asia Standard Time
```

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689962/sql-server-format-date-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss

Comment: Do you want to convert time format?]

Comment: ํYes, I do but wonder how I can synchronise the time zone too.

Comment: I found out that I have to use dbo.UTCToLocalTime instead of dbo.UTCToLocalStringTime to make it convertible. Thank you a lot for help by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),103)+' '+convert(varchar(20),convert(time,getdate()),108)

result:25/10/2018 17:36:03
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This Code : 
this query is not tested Please reply if you are getting any error

```
SELECT
B.Job_ID,
B.Raw_Format,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),b.Raw_Date_Column,106) Raw_Date_Column
FROM
(
SELECT 
    jobid AS 'Job_ID', 
    B.servStartDate AS 'Raw_Format',
    dbo.UTCToLocalStringTime(dbo.GetDateTime(B.servStartDate),@csTimeZone) AS 'Raw_Date_Column'
FROM JMBkpStats B
) AS B
GROUP BY
    B.Job_ID,
B.Raw_Format,
b.Raw_Date_Column
```

Comment: As long as I have tried something like CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),dbo.UTCToLocalStringTime(dbo.GetDateTime(B.servStartDate),@csTimeZone),104), it's still not working (text remains the same).

Comment: what is this part @c‌​sTimeZone

Comment: It is used to convert time into its local time zone as declared above.

Comment: By the way, I found that dbo.UTCtoLocalStringTime will convert time into strings and dbo.UTCtoLocalTime will convert it into datetime. I have to use the latter so that the format can be changed. I think the case is resolved. Thank you very much!